# Java: mkdir by url source

Tags: java

I want to make a Java downloader program, which will download the data from the url to some local default folder, such as /tmp/data.

However, if the url is like: www.site.com/book/1.html, I want to save the file 1.html into /tmp/data/book/1.html.

I don't know how to mkdir recursively, by which I mean make the "book" folder automatically.

The code I make the program to make file is like this:

```
String dataDir = "/tmp/data";
URL url = new URL("http://www.site.com/book/1.html");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(dataDir+url.getFile())));
bw.write(data.toString());
bw.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`mkdirs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29):

```
File dataDir = new File("/tmp/data");
URL url = new URL("http://www.site.com/book/1.html");
final File targetFile = new File(dataDir, url.getFile());
final File targetDir = targetFile.getParentFile();
if (!targetDir.exists() && !targetDir.mkdirs()) {
    throw new SomeException("Failed to create parent directory " + targetDir);
}
// continue using targetFile
```

As you see I also use `File` to represent every path, for the sake of type safety and clearness.

Last but not least: if you simply download a HTML file, I'd not use a `String` to hold its content, because to get the *correct* `String` you'd need to know the HTML files encoding. It's much easier to just handle it as a `byte[]`, which avoids all the encoding-related problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can get Java to create dirs for your by using `mkdirs` method of the `File` class.  For example:

```
String dataDir = "/tmp/data";
Sring filename = "book/1.html";

//this will create all directories recursively as necessary
File out = new File(dataDir, filename);
out.mkdirs();

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(out));
URL url = new URL("http://www.site.com/" + filename);

// get data of URL and write it into your writer

bw.close();
```